# How to find matrix representation relative to two bases.

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if $T: P_2\to P_2$ such that $T(p(x)) = p'(x) + p(x)$

I used the bases $B = \{1-x-x^2,\;1,\;1+x^2\}$ and $B' = \{x^2,\;x,\;1\}$.

I got the matrix $T$ relative to $B,\;B'$ to be $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Is this correct? Or did I not align the rows correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct!

In general, if you have a linear map $\textsf{T} : \textsf{V}\to\textsf{W}$, $\beta = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\gamma = \{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ basis for $\textsf V$ and $\textsf W$, respectively, to obtain the $j$-column of the desired matrix, first compute $\textsf{T}(v_j)$ and then put that as a linear combination of the vectors in $\gamma$, like that
$$\textsf{T}(v_j) = a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2 + \cdots + a_{mj}w_m$$
so, the vector
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{1j} \\ a_{2j} \\ \vdots \\ a_{mj} \end{pmatrix}$$ 
is the $j$-column of the matrix.